# Retrieve the children of a parent node and perform a method on each value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app that needs to retrieve all child from a certain parent node and would like to perform a method call on each child retrieved.

> Here is my current database:

[Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h3JF.png)

I would like to call all child of `conradjr` and on retrieval of a child for example "ranniecardino15", it should store it to a variable then perform a method call. How can I do this?

I have made a code like this but the method call "getCurrentLocation" is only performed on the last child retrieved.

```
 public void getCurrentChildUser() {
    DatabaseReference getuser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Children");
    getuser.child(user).orderByChild("CurrentLocation").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                childuser = childSnapshot.getKey();
                if (childuser != null){

                    getCurrentLocation();

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void getCurrentLocation(){

    DatabaseReference getuser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Children");
    getuser.child(user).child(childuser).child("CurrentLocation").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot != null){

                currentloc = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                System.out.println("Current Location: "+currentloc);
                String split[] = currentloc.split(",");
                lat1 = Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
                lng1 = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
                System.out.println("Current Latitude: "+lat1+" and Current Longitude: "+lng1);
                getSavedLocation();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Please help me :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you say "is only performed on the last child retrieved."? Please add also the content of your `getCurrentLocation()` method.

Comment: i updated my post, I added the getCurrentLocation() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to change the declaration of your `getCurrentLocation()` method from:

```
public void getCurrentLocation(){}
```

to

```
public void getCurrentLocation(String childuser){}
```

Now you need to call this method from inside the `onDataChange()` method like this:

```
getCurrentLocation(childuser);
```

See, I have passed the `childuser` as an argument to the `getCurrentLocation()` so it can be used in a proper way.